# Can't move any elements in Android Studio for RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to add some buttons/textviews or any other components to my relativelayout. I can't place them anywhere but top left. However, if I edit XML code it works fine.

[Here is the screenshot of current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzPMG.png)

I already changed my layout to relativeLayout but still no luck. (Android Studio 3.3)

My layout xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would expect to move these buttons/textviews relative to each other but they just stuck at top left.

Comment: try changing `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`. Else you have to use options like `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` or in the textview `android:layout_alignRight="@id/button"`

Comment: May first you'll read something about [RelativeLayout](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_relative_layout.htm)?

Answer (score 25):

there is a magnetic button on top of view editor its called (on/off auto connect ). if you change it you can move the views inside relative layout.

Comment: Great reasoning here. This really helped me with the latest Android Studio (v3.4) as per today.

Answer (score 19):

Just Enable `AutoConnection to Parent`
In Design Mode click the magnet icon and choose "AutoConnection to Parent"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic code of how you can prevent everything from cluttering in the left corner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

To know more about Positioning Views in a Relative Layout, refer:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative

Answer (score 0):

U did not Render the Relative Layout Rules. You have `layout_alignParentRight` `layout_alignParentLeft` , etc.U should Use Them . For Example, IF u Want Your TextView to be below of The Button U should Write Code Like This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative

Answer (score 0):

If you do not download "SDK Platform Tool" that same as You are using in  "API Version For Preview" Tab which is used for preview XML layout, This problem can occur

Go to
Android XML Visualizer Tool -> Use Design View -> API version for Preview tab

[image: How to Navigate]

After that, Check API Version and Make sure to download the SDK platform tool which is similar to that

Answer (score 0):

Just tick all the layout_alignParentXXXX attributes and then you can see the element move in the parent relative layout with the margins.